# Adding an anonymous Task to List<Task> does not execute it after calling .WaitAll() C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I add a task to a task list the following way

```
taskList.Add(new Task(async () =>
    {
        // work here
        await MethodInsideThatNeedsAwaiting(); // if that has anything to do with it
        // more work 
    }));
```

Calling `Task.WaitAll(tasklist);` afterwards gets "stuck". The program continues to run but there's nothing heard from any tasks from that list anymore nor does it hit any breakpoints as if it's stuck in its own internal async loop somewhere.

Is the way I'm adding the task to the list wrong? What's the issue here?

**What I also tried:**
I've tried the following as well, if for some reason the `async` keyword was the problem, but it still ***doesn't work***:

```
taskList.Add(new Task(() =>
    {
        // work here
        MethodInsideThatNeedsAwaiting().Wait();
        // more work 
    }));
```

This however ***works*** as expected

```
private async Task GetStuff()
{
    // same work here
    await MethodInsideThatNeedsAwaiting();
    // more work
}
```

And then adding it with `taskList.Add(GetStuff());` Calling `Task.WaitAll(tasklist);` has no problems with this one.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are calling `new Task`.  You have an async lambda. The async lambda returns a task.  If you want it to run then *invoke it*. What you're doing is like making a to-do list that says "make a to-do list" but does not say "and do the things on that list"!  Just do the things on the list! You don't need to make a *second* list to tell you to do the things on the first list; you just do them. You've discovered that this is true with your experiments, so it's not clear to me what question you're asking here.

Comment: `You have an async lambda. The async lambda returns a task.` Because, apparently, this part wasn't clear in my head as it should've been. I've seen in a different answer the following construction of a task - `new Task(() =>
                {

                });`  and have simply encapsulated it in an taskList.Add() call.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything that you're doing here is wrong. **Stop what you're doing and learn how this works before you write more asynchronous code.** You are setting yourself up for tasks which never complete because they never started, and for tasks which never complete because they are waiting on themselves. Asynchronous workflows are a little tricky.

First off: you almost never want to use `new Task`.  It just means "make a task that represents this work". **It does not mean to execute that work**.  `new Task` makes a to-do list; it does not do the stuff on the list!

Second, you almost never want to use `Task.Run`.  That means to make a task that represents the work **and assign a worker from the pool to run it**. You don't want to allocate a worker unless the work that you're doing is **synchronous** and **CPU bound**, which your work is not.

Third, you almost never want to use either on something that is **already a task**.  You have an async lambda in hand. **It returns a task when invoked, so if you want a task for a running workflow, invoke the lambda!**

Fourth, you almost never want to `WaitAll`.  **That destroys the whole point of asynchrony by turning an asynchronous workflow back into a synchronous workflow**.

Fifth, you almost never want to call `Wait` on a task, for the same reason. But it gets worse!  Here's a to-do list I'd like you to do:  First, put the bread in the toaster and start it toasting. Second, synchronously wait for the sandwich to be done; do not move on until this step is complete. Third, eat the sandwich. Fourth, when the toaster pops, take the toast out of the toaster, and put some ham on the toast to make a sandwich.  **You will wait forever if you try to execute this workflow**.  Asynchronous workflows **deadlock** when you insert synchronous waits into them **because you are often in a situation where you are waiting on work that you yourself are going to do in the future**.

(An aside about that last point:  if you are in that situation, the correct solution is *NOT* to change the second step of the workflow to "hire a worker to complete my sandwich, and synchronously wait for that worker to be done".  You often see this sort of bizarre, wasteful fix to an incorrect workflow.  **When you remove synchronous waits and insert asynchronous waits (`await`) at points where the workflow cannot continue until a task is complete then you will find that your workflows can be done all one one thread**.)

**Everything you are doing is absolutely the wrong way to do asynchronous programming, and you will not be successful if you keep on doing it like this**.

OK, so now that you know how not to do it, how do you do it?

- If you have a method or lambda that returns a task, **invoke it to get the task**.
- If you need to wait for that task to complete before your workflow can continue, `await` the task.
- If you have several tasks and you need them all to complete before your workflow can continue, **put them in a collection and then call `WhenAll` to get a new task back that represents the task of completing all those tasks**.  Then you must `await` *that* task.

Some correct workflows:

Here's the simplest one:

```
private async Task GetStuffAsync()
{
    // same work here
    await MethodInsideThatNeedsAwaitingAsync();
    // more work
}
private async Task DoItAsync()
{
    // do work
    await GetStuffAsync();
    // do more work
}
```

What if you have multiple tasks and you want to wait for all of them, but they don't have to wait for each other?

```
private async Task DoItAsync()
{
    // do work
    Task t1 = GetStuffAsync();
    // do work
    Task t2 = GetOtherStuffAsync();
    // do more work
    // We cannot continue until both are done
    await t1;
    await t2;
    // do even more work
}
```

What if you have an *unknown* number of such tasks?

```
private async Task DoItAsync()
{
    // do work
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    while (whatever)
      tasks.Add(GetStuffAsync()); 
    // do work
    // we cannot continue until all tasks are done
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // do more work
}
```

Comment: Harsh but fair. =) As a quick defensive note, I've actually wrote it in my code as `await WhenAll(...)`, but couldn't click to the difference when writing the question which might be even worse. And _Thank you!_ for the quick lecture.

Comment: @Derptastic: Not intended to be harsh; intended to be *extremely clear that there is a wrong way to do this and you're doing it*.  I want it to be extremely clear to all readers that asynchronous workflows are, like all workflows, *composed out of parts that have control flow relationships*, and that you need to know what those relationships are to be successful at this.  If you saw a novice programmer mixing up `if` and `while`, you'd again have to be *very clear* that sure, those are *closely related* control flows, but they are not the same.